# Algebraic extension by $\sqrt{-7}$

Tags: maple

In trying to find the Galois group of a polynomial, I am trying to see if adjoining $\sqrt{-7}$ can split the polynomial but entering factor(x^2 + 7 , $\sqrt{-7}$) is invalid. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What factors do you expect?

Comment: The factors should be $(x - \sqrt{-7})(x + \sqrt{-7})$ I don't want to have to introduce the whole set of complex numbers.

Comment: Fine. In Maple, just multiply those factors, then expand the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is with the particular Maple syntax?

```
factor(x^2+7, (-7)^(1/2));

           /         (1/2)\ /        (1/2)\
          -\-x + (-7)     / \x + (-7)     /
```

note:

```
sqrt(-7);

                     (1/2)
                  I 7     

(-7)^(1/2);

                      (1/2)
                  (-7)
```

And you were trying not to have to do it like this?

```
factor(x^2+7, {sqrt(-1),sqrt(7)});

            /   (1/2)    \ /   (1/2)    \
           -\I 7      - x/ \I 7      + x/
```